# How to use curl with xampp in windows?

Tags: laravel, curl, xampp

I am facing issue in testing laravel API while using curl.
I am following tutorial https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial
When I use command on CMD, I get error.
The command is:

```
    curl -X POST localhost/api/register \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"name": "John", "email": "john.doe@toptal.com", "password": "toptal123", "password_confirmation": "toptal123"}'
```

The error is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost" /> 

<title>Redirecting to http://localhost</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost">http://localhost</a>. 
</body> 
</html>curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \ 

C:\xampp\htdocs\top> -H "Accept: application/json" \ 
’-H’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

C:\xampp\htdocs\top> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
’-H’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

    C:\xampp\htdocs\top> -d ’{"name": "John", "email": "john.doe@toptal.com", "password": "toptal123", "password_confirmatio
n": "toptal123"}’
```

Please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: i think CMD doesn't recognize the backslash as line continuation. You will have to put everything on one line

Comment: using in one line, and now the error is:   {"name":["The name field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is requ
ired."]}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: John, 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: email 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: toptal.com, 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: toptal123, 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password_confirmation 
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the command in one line by removing backslashes before header and adding backslashes in the data. Now this command worked for me:
curl -X POST localhost/api/register -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"Amir\", \"email\": \"abc@gmail.com\", \"password\": \"Amir123\", \"password_confirmation\": \"Amir123\"}"